Why does (name) se robo mean (name) stole?
What function is 'se' serving here?
I tried searching on ecosia but was not able to find an answer.

In Spain is more common to say "(name) robó las joyas". The use of the additional (se) is more frequently in SouthAmerica.

What do you actually mean? Please write out the sentence in full. Juan se robo, means nothing, for example. Se le robo el coche means: His car was stolen.

Welcome to Spanish. Visit the [tour] to learn how the site works and earn your first badge. Here in América, as a response to that you can hear "Yo no me robé las joyas"

@Glorfindel Can I have a quick chat with you in the chat? Thanks.

In "Se robó las joyas", "se" is a dative of interest, also called an "ethical dative", that may suggest:

He stole the jewels for himself. (emphasis on his own benefit)

He stole all the jewels. (emphasis on the completeness of the action)

He stole the jewels and got away with it. (emphasis on his success in stealing)



I saw it  in this video

Perhaps it is in the sense that he stole them for himself?

“Zac se robó una colonia de urones de patas negras y huyó con ella” was the sentence according to subtitles

Should be "hurones" with an "h".

All three meanings are implied: a whole pack of ferrets, for himself and got away with it.

But they didn’t all get stolen and Zach didn’t end up getting away with it

The subtitles say urones

It is a mistake.

It doesn't matter how things turned out in the end. At the time, he managed to do it.

"Pedro robó las joyas" is the same as "Pedro se robó las joyas".
The "se" means itself, so is like saying "Peter stole something to himself" which has no sense so, I suppose It's just a difference between Spanish from Spain and Spanish from LATAM where is more commonly used "se robó" than in Spain.
For a Spanish (from Spain) speaker "se robó" sound strange but it is understandable.

I do not think all of LATAM uses se robó like that.

Perhaps you meant "Peter stole something for himself".
